# Implementing Index trait with u32 to index a custom string type

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I wrote the below program to implement `Index` trait for a custom type.

```
use std::ops::Index;

struct StringWrapper(String);

impl Index<usize> for StringWrapper {
    type Output = char;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.0.chars().nth(index).expect("error")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = StringWrapper(String::from("Hello!"));

    println!("{}", s[0]);
}
```

I am facing using with the line:

```
&self.0.chars().nth(index).expect("error")
```

The compiler throws the below error:

> cannot return reference to temporary value returns a reference to data
> owned by the current function

I understand that the `chars()` creates a new iterator within the function and a reference to it is returned back. Since the iterator doesn't outlive the function, the compiler throws the error.

Is there any other way on how i can handle this?

Comment: You cannot implement that index (at least, not without weird tricks). But it is good you cannot: it is very easy to write innocent-looking `for i in 0..s.len() { s[i] }`, but this will have quadratic complexity.

Comment: If you really do need the ability to index, why not use `Vec<char>` instead of `String`? (But beware that `char` is not what humans think of as "character").